# How to change default bullets in Impress?

Tags: openoffice.org, bulletedlist, openoffice-impress

I tried to use `F11 -> Presentation styles -> Outline (1 .. 9) -> Modify -> Customize`
Then I changed bullet to my graphics, but it doesn't help.

How to do it properly?

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.

The Openoffice version is 5.1.4.2

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, OpenOffice Impress does not support the same styles as Writer, and list styles / numbering styles are missing. I think recent versions of LibreOffice have fixed this issue, but in the lastest version of OpenOffice it still exists. My struggle with spontaneous changes of list formatting when resizing / copying lists was the reason why I eventually decided to buy Powerpoint. Also, I could not find any online information about this issue except: https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=38382. Hope that helps.